# Configure apache to listen on port other than 80

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to configure apache to listen on port 8079
I added LISTEN 8079 directive in httpd.conf
I opened 8079 port in iptables / restarted iptables etc. I even stopped iptables service.
"netstat -nal | grep 8079" shows "tcp 0 0 :::8079 :::* LISTEN"

Now, if I try to access localhost:8079 or myserver.com:8079 from that machine, I can access that page
BUT from any other machine I am not able to access the site on any port other than 80. On port 80, it works. On port 8079 it does not.

what else do I need to configure???? Please help.

If it matters, I use centOS server. You can see my httpd.conf file here  fileuploading.net/860467
I am not using any third party software - compiled apache, tomcat and jk connector from source.

Thanks

UPDATE::::::::
It was a firewall issue. There was a hardware firewall that was blocking access to almost all ports. (Turning off software firewall / SELinux bla bla had no effect)

Then I scanned the open ports and used the port that was open. (came to know about this command many days later)

If you are facing the same problem, Run the following command

sudo nmap -T Aggressive -A -v 127.0.0.1 -p 1-65000

It will scan for all the open ports on your system. Any port that is open can be accessed from outside.

Ref.: http://www.go2linux.org/which_service_or_program_is_listening_on_port

Comment: Can you amplify how it doesn't work? Presumably you are getting "connection refused" or similar? What do nmap or wget from other computer say?

Comment: Could not connect to server through browser
wget says connection refused.

Comment: You've got firewall issues, this has nothing to do with Apache.

Comment: yeah chris, it is a firewall issue and I am supposed to solve it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you perhaps have a hardware firewall or similar device between the other machines and this webserver? If so, the firewall might be [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) connections incoming on port 80 on the firewall from the test machines to go to port 8079 on the webserver instead, and you will need to modify the firewall's configuration.

Comment: yeah, your aswer is almost correct. I had to get information about hardware firewall from someone else. And you proved right :-) Anyway, there's a simpler way i.e. of port scanning. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You disabled firewall from Centos? execute setup command, then go to "Firewall configuration" and on "Security Level" mark Disabled option.. I also had problem with that.

Neto